# Getting number of members and servers a bot is serving

Tags: discord, discord.js

So I went through the discord.js guide, and found that `client.guilds.size` and `client.users.size` is for finding no of users and servers a bot is on. But when I implement it I get "undefined". Any reason why?

Answer (score 1):

Try `client.guilds.cache.size` and `client.users.cache.size`.
This changed in discord.js v12.

> [client.users has been changed from a Collection to a Manager.](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#client-users)
>
> [client.guilds has been changed from a Collection to a Manager.](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#client-guilds)